# Creating Kettle Database Repository via Command Line (.bat)

Tags: batch-file, command-line, pentaho, etl

I would like to create a kettle database repository by using a batch script or simply command lines. I got my database user etc. and PDI 6.1.0.1 installed. So far I found nothing on creating a new repository - only on Import/Export using Kitchen and Pan.

Thanks!

Comment: In 6.1, it was in the Top Menu / Tools / Create Repository...

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?150524-How-to-create-new-file-repository-on-Linux-with-command-line-interface)

I see a three step process:

1. Create a directory in a suitable place on your Linux system using mkdir
2. Register this directory as a file repository with Kettle using spoon
3. Deploy your jobs and transactions from Windows to Linux

PS: 
In case nobody has access to spoon on the server, you can modify repositories.xml directly.
If you don't feel comfortable with sed and the like, you can use your local spoon and transfer the XML file.